# Add new Region to existing Page Template

Tags: dxa, cme, dxa2.2

We have noticed an issue when a new Region has been added to the PT. I will try to describe the steps:

- Created Regions Schemas A, B, C
- Created Page schema with given Regions A, B, C
- Created Page Template with given Page Schema
- Created 10 Pages based on that PT
- Published and working
- After some time, it was decided to add a new Region D to that PT, so

  - new Region Schema D is created
  - existing Page Schema is updated in order to add a new Region
- Go to any Page based on PT and open, however, there is no Component Presentations previously added to regions A, B, C.
- Checked in CM DB and page json in db has still all CPs with information to which region it belongs it.

What is causing this issue?

It is not expected behavior if every PT update with add/remove regions will cause losing previously added CPs.

It is DXA 2.2 and SDL Web 9.0

Comment: please share your tridion and DXA version

Comment: Updated in post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the "normal" behavior in Sites 9. Changing the Page Schema or Region Schemas and opening already existing pages in the CME results in "regenerating" the Regions, which means losing the CPs.

In Sites 9.1, this [was improved upon](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/745071/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/content-manager-functionality-introduced-in-------------sdl-tridion-sites-9-1) by expanding on the synchronization methods to cover those scenarios. Additionally, the CME is also smarter and now a Page is validated and synchronized against its Schema. This means that the CPs are not, they remain in their respective Regions. Those which are orphaned will end up in the Main Region.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK - It's a known issue. Please refer to the below link for more information. I vaguely remember I think it was fixed in one of the versions.

https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000009269

https://docs.rws.com/792149/107667/sdl-tridion-sites-9/known-issues-in-content-manager